# Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{A}$ a $\sigma-$algebra in $X$. Prove if:

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{A}$ a $\sigma-$algebra in $X$. Prove if:

i) $\forall\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\mathbb{A}$ then,

ii) $\forall\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\mathbb{A}$

**My attempt:**

As, we know $\forall\,a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\mathbb{A}$ then in particular for $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\mathbb{A}$.

Is good this?

**Other question:**

If $\forall\,a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ we have $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\mathbb{A}$ then 
$\forall\, a\subset\mathbb{R}$ $f^{-1}(<a,\infty))\in\mathbb{A}$

Note:$<a,\infty)$ include $(a,\infty)$ and $[a,\infty)$

For this i don't have a clear idea of how solve this.

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\cup f^{-1} (r,n)$ where the union is taken over all integers $n >a$ and all rational numbers $r \in (a,n)$.